# Can not get the proper reply Shopify API Authentication

Tags: api, oauth, shopify

I wanted to integrate shopify into my software.It is a desktop application.
I had went through API Docs of shopify.
Those API's would properly bring up data from my sandbox account using API key and password.

Then i came accross 'API Authentication' in shopify.
After reading those docs i was confused.
The replies after step1(http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html) was not proper.

My question is do i really need Authentication to get API response?
If not then what is the purpose of 'API Authentication'.

Plz help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it you've generated a private application to get your api key and password, and are passing those credentials through basic auth (i.e. in the url). This is fine.

The authentication topic you found is for public apps that are installed into many shops. They deal with generating the auth token, which does the same job as the password you already have.

So sum up: Yes, you need to authenticate to the API in order to use it but you're already doing that by using the password from your private app. Don't worry about OAuth unless you're building a public app that will be installed into many shops.